# Cmake external optional package add

Tags: cmake

I'm new to Cmake and trying to build a KDE project (okular) which requires an optional package(libspectre). I did a default make install and the library files are in the location "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu".

In the generators/CMakeLists.txt, I tried to replace the "macro_optional_find_package(LibSpectre)" with the following:

```
find_library(LIBSPECTRE_LIBRARY NAMES libspectre PATHS "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/")

include(FindPackageHandleStandardArgs)
find_package_handle_standard_args(LibSpectre DEFAULT_MSG LIBSPECTRE_LIBRARY)
```

Which seems to not find the libspectre library. I tried replacing PATHS with HINTS and also changing 'libspectre' to 'spectre' after NAMES. But it doesn't seem to recognize.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: What is **exact name** (with extension) of the library's file (under `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/`) which you *want to find*? Are you sure, that given `find_library()` call is executed? (Try to add `message()` call after it). As you build project for yourself, it is better just to set `LIBSPECTRE_LIBRARY` variable in CMake cache. No needs to modify scripts for that.

Comment: Hi, The name of the library file is **libspectre.so.1**. It's a symlink to _libspectre.so.1.1.7_. I will try your suggestions. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CMake doesn't aware about library's *so-version*, it checks only precize `.so` extension.

You may create `libspectre.so` - symlink to `libspectre.so.1`. So

```
find_library(LIBSPECTRE_LIBRARY NAMES spectre PATHS "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/")
```

will work.